# Kafka Error INVALID_ARG No Such configuration property sasl.mechanisms when using confluent-kafka-python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, confluent-platform, message-hub

When trying to use the Message Hub Bluemix service with confluent-kafka-python, I am getting the   ERROR    Uncaught exception: , KafkaError{code=_INVALID_ARG,val=-186,str="No such configuration property: "sasl.mechanisms""}

Comment: Can you share the code related to the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that librdkafka (the library confluent-kafka-python wraps) has not been compiled with SASL support.

Please ensure you have the required dependencies installed on your system and reinstall librdkafka

For Linux:

- libsasl2-dev
- libsasl2-modules

For macOS and more details, see our documentation about librdkafka: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/message-hub-samples/blob/master/docs/librdkafka.md